# In python pandas, count the integers in a particular column and also count all the elements in particular column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

There is a huge df with multiple columns but want to read only specific column that is interested to me:

in the below data, I would like to read only the column 'Type 1'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Type 1': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 'HH', 4: 9, 5: 11, 6: 13, 7: 15, 8: 17},
         'Type 2': {0: 'AA',
          1: 'BB',
          2: 'np.NaN',
          3: '55',
          4: '3.14',
          5: '-96',
          6: 'String',
          7: 'FFFFFF',
          8: 'FEEE'},
         'Type 3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0},
         'Type 4': {0: '23',
          1: 'fefe',
          2: 'abcd',
          3: 'dddd',
          4: 'dad',
          5: 'cfe',
          6: 'cf42',
          7: '321',
          8: '0'},
         'Type 5': {0: -120,
          1: -120,
          2: -120,
          3: -120,
          4: -120,
          5: -120,
          6: -120,
          7: -120,
          8: -120}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
int_count = df['Type 1'].count(0,numeric_only = True) # should count only cells that contain integers and return 8
total_count = df['Type 1'].count(0,numeric_only = False) # should count all the cells and return 9
```

I want something like count only the numeric values in particular column

eg: df['Type 1'].count(0,numeric_only = True) should return 8 (exclude counting the string 'HH' in Type 1 column)

df['Type 1'].count(0,numeric_only = False) should return 9 (total number of cells in the particular column)

but "df['Type 1'].count(0,numeric_only = True/False)" this is not working as I expect...

Comment: There is a difference between [`pd.DataFrame.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html#pandas-dataframe-count) and [`pd.Series.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html#pandas.Series.count)

Comment: In `pd.DataFrame.count`, the numeric_only parameter will take only count columns that have a datatype of 'int', 'float' or 'boolean'.   It does not look at the elements in the column series.  Because you have a 'string' in a column, the dtype for column is casted as 'o' object and is thus non-numeric as pd.Series.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the below:

```
int_count = len(df.loc[df['Type 1'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()])
total_count = len(df)
```

Comment: negative numbers are not counted by isnumeric() method

Comment: Correct. You could then create a new column with the absolute value and apply the isnumeric() method on it.